# How to extract features with different percentile from the density plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to extract features-compounds lying in different percentile (25th, 50th, 75th) from the density plot. Then save these features in the new `data.frame`. I will then use these new features and map with the original `data.frame`. Identification of these features would help in further analysis and in-depth exploration. I have provided example data and density/boxplot (screenshot below).

```
dput(Delta)
structure(list(`PC1-PC2` = c(0.0161933528045602, 0.766612235998576, 
                             -0.237724873642335, -0.0733015604900428, 0.400545815637124, 0.414481719044214, 
                             0.208303811501068, 0.392408339922047, 0.336514581021898, -0.320322998122561, 
                             0.36615463065484, -0.263557666645363, 0.180272570114807, 0.255255831254277, 
                             0.0138502697450574, 0.23798933387042, -0.296936870921566, 0.206190306805568, 
                             0.141038353337885, 0.167942308239497, 0.147174778368622, -0.0111611567646942, 
                             -0.141468109519736, 0.11179112137823, 0.114216799808335, 0.0185917572079534, 
                             0.0147028493400293), Gene_Symbols = structure(c(15L, 13L, 21L, 
                                                                             9L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 19L, 14L, 5L, 17L, 24L, 18L, 8L, 27L, 20L, 12L, 
                                                                             26L, 4L, 23L, 3L, 6L, 16L, 22L, 11L, 25L, 10L), .Label = c("Feature_1_Compound_2", 
                                                                                                                                        "Feature_1_Compound_3", "Feature_10_Compound_1", "Feature_10_Compound_2", 
                                                                                                                                        "Feature_10_Compound_3", "Feature_2_Compound_2", "Feature_2_Compound_3", 
                                                                                                                                        "Feature_3_Compound_1", "Feature_3_Compound_2", "Feature_4_Compound_1", 
                                                                                                                                        "Feature_4_Compound_2", "Feature_4_Compound_3", "Feature_5_Compound_1", 
                                                                                                                                        "Feature_5_Compound_2", "Feature_5_Compound_3", "Feature_6_Compound_1", 
                                                                                                                                        "Feature_6_Compound_2", "Feature_6_Compound_3", "Feature_7_Compound_1", 
                                                                                                                                        "Feature_7_Compound_2", "Feature_7_Compound_3", "Feature_8_Compound_1", 
                                                                                                                                        "Feature_8_Compound_2", "Feature_8_Compound_3", "Feature_9_Compound_1", 
                                                                                                                                        "Feature_9_Compound_2", "Feature_9_Compound_3"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("Feature_5_Compound_3", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "Feature_5_Compound_1", "Feature_7_Compound_3", "Feature_3_Compound_2", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "Feature_1_Compound_3", "Feature_2_Compound_3", "Feature_1_Compound_2", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "Feature_7_Compound_1", "Feature_5_Compound_2", "Feature_10_Compound_3", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "Feature_6_Compound_2", "Feature_8_Compound_3", "Feature_6_Compound_3", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "Feature_3_Compound_1", "Feature_9_Compound_3", "Feature_7_Compound_2", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "Feature_4_Compound_3", "Feature_9_Compound_2", "Feature_10_Compound_2", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "Feature_8_Compound_2", "Feature_10_Compound_1", "Feature_2_Compound_2", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "Feature_6_Compound_1", "Feature_8_Compound_1", "Feature_4_Compound_2", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "Feature_9_Compound_1", "Feature_4_Compound_1"), class = "data.frame")


#>                           PC1-PC2          Gene_Symbols
#> Feature_5_Compound_3   0.01619335  Feature_5_Compound_3
#> Feature_5_Compound_1   0.76661224  Feature_5_Compound_1
#> Feature_7_Compound_3  -0.23772487  Feature_7_Compound_3
#> Feature_3_Compound_2  -0.07330156  Feature_3_Compound_2
#> Feature_1_Compound_3   0.40054582  Feature_1_Compound_3
#> Feature_2_Compound_3   0.41448172  Feature_2_Compound_3
#> Feature_1_Compound_2   0.20830381  Feature_1_Compound_2
#> Feature_7_Compound_1   0.39240834  Feature_7_Compound_1
#> Feature_5_Compound_2   0.33651458  Feature_5_Compound_2
#> Feature_10_Compound_3 -0.32032300 Feature_10_Compound_3
#> Feature_6_Compound_2   0.36615463  Feature_6_Compound_2
#> Feature_8_Compound_3  -0.26355767  Feature_8_Compound_3
#> Feature_6_Compound_3   0.18027257  Feature_6_Compound_3
#> Feature_3_Compound_1   0.25525583  Feature_3_Compound_1
#> Feature_9_Compound_3   0.01385027  Feature_9_Compound_3
#> Feature_7_Compound_2   0.23798933  Feature_7_Compound_2
#> Feature_4_Compound_3  -0.29693687  Feature_4_Compound_3
#> Feature_9_Compound_2   0.20619031  Feature_9_Compound_2
#> Feature_10_Compound_2  0.14103835 Feature_10_Compound_2
#> Feature_8_Compound_2   0.16794231  Feature_8_Compound_2
#> Feature_10_Compound_1  0.14717478 Feature_10_Compound_1
#> Feature_2_Compound_2  -0.01116116  Feature_2_Compound_2
#> Feature_6_Compound_1  -0.14146811  Feature_6_Compound_1
#> Feature_8_Compound_1   0.11179112  Feature_8_Compound_1
#> Feature_4_Compound_2   0.11421680  Feature_4_Compound_2
#> Feature_9_Compound_1   0.01859176  Feature_9_Compound_1
#> Feature_4_Compound_1   0.01470285  Feature_4_Compound_1


# Density distribution
plt2 <- ggdensity(Delta, x = "PC1-PC2", y = "..count..",
                  xlab = "Delta (PC1-PC2)",
                  ylab = "Number of genes",
                  fill = "lightgray", color = "black",
                  label = "Gene_Symbols", repel = TRUE,
                  font.label = list(color= "PC1-PC2"),
                  xticks.by = 20, # Break x ticks by 20
                  gradient.cols = c("blue", "red"),
                  legend = c(0.7, 0.6),                                 
                  legend.title = ""       # Hide legend title
)
#

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

plt1 <- Delta %>% select(`PC1-PC2`) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x="", y = `PC1-PC2`)) +
  geom_boxplot(fill = "lightblue", color = "black") + 
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic() +
  xlab("") +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())


# install.packages("egg", dependencies = TRUE)
egg::ggarrange(plt2, plt1, heights = 2:1)
```

[image]

Thank You,

Toufiq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract feature between 25th and 75th percentile of PC1-PC2:

```
Delta %>% filter(`PC1-PC2` >= quantile(Delta$`PC1-PC2`, .25) &
                   `PC1-PC2` <= quantile(Delta$`PC1-PC2`, .75) )

                         PC1-PC2          Gene_Symbols
Feature_5_Compound_3  0.01619335  Feature_5_Compound_3
Feature_1_Compound_2  0.20830381  Feature_1_Compound_2
Feature_6_Compound_3  0.18027257  Feature_6_Compound_3
Feature_9_Compound_3  0.01385027  Feature_9_Compound_3
Feature_7_Compound_2  0.23798933  Feature_7_Compound_2
Feature_9_Compound_2  0.20619031  Feature_9_Compound_2
Feature_10_Compound_2 0.14103835 Feature_10_Compound_2
Feature_8_Compound_2  0.16794231  Feature_8_Compound_2
Feature_10_Compound_1 0.14717478 Feature_10_Compound_1
Feature_8_Compound_1  0.11179112  Feature_8_Compound_1
Feature_4_Compound_2  0.11421680  Feature_4_Compound_2
Feature_9_Compound_1  0.01859176  Feature_9_Compound_1
Feature_4_Compound_1  0.01470285  Feature_4_Compound_1
```